# Delete line of structure array and update it in tab vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

So I have a listbox, filled with informations from a structure tab as follows :

```
Private Sub Modifier_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix.Length - 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix(i).strTitre)
    Next
End Sub
```

And I want the user to choose to delete the TabPolyFlix(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) and it has to get updated in the original Tab and thus in the Listbox

P.S I tried this but it only updates it in the listbox, not in the original tab

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Temp As New List(Of ListViewItem)

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(i) = False Then
            Temp.Add(ListBox1.Items(i))
        End If
    Next

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    For i As Integer = 0 To Temp.Count - 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Temp(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a fixed size. Better use a `List(Of ListViewItem)` for `TabPolyFlix`. Then assign the List directly to the `DataSource` of the listbox:

```
'Fill the listbox
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "strTitre" 'You can also set this in the property grid.
ListBox1.DataSource = frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix
```

You can also override the `ToString` method of `ListViewItem` in order to display anything you want in the listbox and keep `ListBox1.DisplayMember` empty.

Now you can directly delete the item in the list:

```
frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

or

```
frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

or if you want to delete several items at once

```
For Each i As Integer In ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast(Of Integer)()
    frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix.Remove(ListBox1.Items(i))
Next
```

and re-display the list:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
ListBox1.DataSource = frmConnecter.TabPolyFlix
```

---

The moral of the story is: don't use controls (the ListBox in this case) as your primary data structure. Use it only for display and user interaction. Perform the logic (the so called business logic) on display-independent data structures and objects (so called business objects) and when finished, display the result.